# Where does Visual Studio load the HTML in cache somewhere?

Tags: html, asp.net, angular, visual-studio

I have a simple Web app csproj containing an Angular2+ app. I use Visual Studio 2017 Pro and Google Chrome during IDE debugging. Sometimes, I had found that Visual Studio insists on loading older HTML template files cached somewhere after I had made changes to those files.

1. I had cleared Chrome cache prior to running the IDE debugger.
2. Cleared %temp%
3. Cleared C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

VS IDE still got the old HTML template files somewhere. And the strange thing is, if I run a batch script against .vs\config\applicatiohost.config to host the Web app in IIS Express, IIS Express could load the current HTML template files in current project folder correctly. I know VS IDE actually does similar thing as well, but somehow manage to ask IIS Express to load the HTML file elsewhere?

Do you happen to know where VS IDE with IIS Express cache the HTML files of the Web project?

Answer (score 1):

This is caching, and it's pain. You can cancel caching while in develop mode using chrome dev tools:

**disable cache by navigating to the Network Tab and ticking Disable Cache**:
[image]

See if this help you clearing things out.

Use this to help get rid of cache:

```
    if (!$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get) {
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.get = {};
    }

//disable IE ajax request caching
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['If-Modified-Since'] = 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT';
// extra
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.get['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
```

Comment: It does help, though this does not explain why when running IIS Express alone without VS IDE, Chrome could pickup the update files. It seems that "Clear browsing data" of Chrome does not really clear the all the cache. And the cache working with VS IDE somehow is left alone. I still want to know how to clear all the cache in advance. I have proper versioning of html and javascript files, so having to clear cache like this is pain.

Comment: I will attach a method here so you can see, in angular. Not angular 2 but angular js altough still useful.

Comment: Angular has the other ways. for HTML, use clearCache. And for JS, just define timestamp in system.config.js. All these work well in IIS or IIS Express without VS IDE.

Comment: This did not help me, IIS express or something else is holding on to cached files.